# Grails XML changes does not reflect until the server is re-started

Tags: xml, grails

I have XML file which i am using in Grails Application. I keep updating xml file on regular basis.

If i update the xml file, the changes are not reflecting until i re-boot the server.

Is there a way to see the changes without rebooting the server.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the pedantic question, but by "re-boot the server" do you really mean reboot the OS, or restart the web server? And do you mean run-app or is this a deployed war file in Tomcat or another container?

Comment: I would also add to Burt's questions, where do these XML files exist in your grails structure?

Answer (score 0):

In Grails 1.4 release notes, they claim to have increased their support of hot code reload.

> Reloading Agent
>
> There is a new JVM-agent that handles
>   reloading of classes making it
>   possible to reload changes to domain
>   classes, statically typed services and
>   more cases that weren't supported
>   before.

As of grails 1.3.7 and before, there are a number of things that force you to restart your grails application : Changes to domain classes, commands, configs and xml files.

Maybe upgrading to 1.4 M2 will solve your problem.

Regards,

Vincent Giguère